# QR Factorization of Rank Deficient Matrix in Julia?

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, scientific-computing

If (in Julia) we compute the QR factorization of a rank deficient matrix like A=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9], some of the diagonal entries of the R matrix will be **very small**. However, when doing this numerically in Julia, how small must these diagonal entries be to be considered zero (thus rank deficient)? I am trying to find a formula for this rather than an absolute number.

Answer (score 0):

If your original matrix `A` can be thought of as *exactly* rank deficient, but with some additive noise, the small-bug-nonzero elements of the diagonal of `R` that should be ignored will be about the same size as the noise in `A`.

For example,

```
julia> d = Diagonal(-5*log.(rand(5)))
5×5 Diagonal{Float64, Vector{Float64}}:
 5.56654    ⋅       ⋅        ⋅         ⋅ 
  ⋅       17.6294   ⋅        ⋅         ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅      2.20874   ⋅         ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅       2.91583    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅        ⋅       26.5664
julia> A = [d zeros(5,3); zeros(3,8)]
8×8 SparseArrays.SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64} with 5 stored entries:
 5.56654    ⋅       ⋅        ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅       17.6294   ⋅        ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅      2.20874   ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅       2.91583    ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅        ⋅       26.5664   ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅        ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅        ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 
  ⋅         ⋅       ⋅        ⋅         ⋅       ⋅    ⋅    ⋅ 

julia> diag(qr(A).R)
8-element SparseArrays.SparseVector{Float64, Int64} with 5 stored entries:
  [1]  =  5.56654
  [2]  =  17.6294
  [3]  =  2.20874
  [4]  =  2.91583
  [5]  =  26.5664

julia> diag(qr(A+rand(8,8)*1e-6).R)
8-element Vector{Float64}:
  -5.566543507821689
 -17.629411781406233
  -2.20873750628613
  -2.915828986361413
 -26.56641073082019
  -1.1241491098747558e-6
  -6.122032725632311e-7
  -2.3444092119580006e-7
```